# Tricky to read XML from web service C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, xpath, nodes

I have looked everywhere, and cannot find anything to help me.

I am writing a program that connects to a webservice and then the webservice sends an XML response.  After the response is received I have to retrieve certain values from it, but this is where it gets tricky

Here is a snippet of the returned XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Response xmlns="http://blabla.com/service/">Successful</Response>
  <ResponseNumber xmlns="http://blabla.com/service/">0</ResponseNumber>
  <SellingCategoriesHierarchy xmlns="http://tym2sell.com/PortalService/">
    <Response>Successful</Response>
    <ResponseNumber>0</ResponseNumber>
    <SellingCategories>
      <PortalSellingCategory>
        <SellingCategoryId xsi:nil="true" />
        <SellingCategoryName>category1</SellingCategoryName>
        <DeliveryMethod />
        <DeliveryMethodNumber>0</DeliveryMethodNumber>
        <SellingCategories>
          <PortalSellingCategory>
            <SellingCategoryId xsi:nil="true" />
            <SellingCategoryName>category1_Item</SellingCategoryName>
            <DeliveryMethod />
            <DeliveryMethodNumber>0</DeliveryMethodNumber>
            <SellingCategories>
              <PortalSellingCategory>
                <SellingCategoryId>2</SellingCategoryId>
                <SellingCategoryName>Item2</SellingCategoryName>
                <DeliveryMethod>Display</DeliveryMethod>
                <DeliveryMethodNumber>1</DeliveryMethodNumber>
                <VoucherValue>0.00</VoucherValue>
                <IsVariablePrice>true</IsVariablePrice>
                <MinimumVoucherValue>1.00</MinimumVoucherValue>
                <MaximumVoucherValue>1000.00</MaximumVoucherValue>
                <VoucherValueIncrement>1.00</VoucherValueIncrement>
                <AdditionalInputItems>
                  <PortalAdditionalInputItem>
                    <InputItemId>-1</InputItemId>
                    <Label>Value:</Label>
                    <IsNumericOnly>true</IsNumericOnly>
                    <MaximumLength>7</MaximumLength>
                    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
                  </PortalAdditionalInputItem>
                  <PortalAdditionalInputItem>
                    <InputItemId>4</InputItemId>
                    <Label>Mobile Number</Label>
                    <IsNumericOnly>true</IsNumericOnly>
                    <MaximumLength>15</MaximumLength>
                    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
                  </PortalAdditionalInputItem>
                </AdditionalInputItems>
                <TwoStep>false</TwoStep>
                <SelectedIcon>SamplePicture</SelectedIcon>
                <UnSelectedIcon>SamplePicture</UnSelectedIcon>
```

This repeats from the SellingCategories node just under Response for a couple of times.
Here is a Snippet of my code where I get the XML as string.

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(receivedData);

        XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy");
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            string sellingCategoryName = xn["SellingCategoryName"].InnerText;
            string SelectedIcon = xn["SelectedIcon"].InnerText;
            string UnSelectedIcon = xn["UnSelectedIcon"].InnerText;
            richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("Name: {0} {1} {2}", sellingCategoryName, SelectedIcon, UnSelectedIcon));
        }
```

I have tried changing `xml.SelectNodes("/MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy");`
to 
`xml.SelectNodes("/MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy/SellingCategoriesHierarchy/SellingCategories/PortalSellingCategory");`

I need to select each SellingCategoryName and list the SellingCategoryName(s) and all the other items underneath it.

I was hoping to get something in the lines of:

Category1

Category1_Item

Item2

SamplePicture

Sample Picture

Mine only reads the First Node and then returns "Successful" to me.

I havve also tried:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("FilePath");
                var sellingCategoryNames = from PortalSellingCategory in root.Elements("MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy")
                                           where (string)PortalSellingCategory.Element("SellingCategoriesHierarchy").Element("SellingCategories").Element("PortalSellingCategory") != ""
                                           select PortalSellingCategory;
                foreach (var xEle in sellingCategoryNames)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = (string)xEle;
                }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend using LINQ to XML here. I suspect it's namespaces that are messing you up to start with, and LINQ to XML makes namespaces a lot easier. Next, you appear to be looking for a `SellingCategoryName` directly within a `MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy` whereas actually there are a few layers involved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing with

```
xml.SelectNodes("/MobilePortalSellingCategoriesHierarchy");
```

is selecting your root node, which is just one. Thats why you only get one item in your list back. Is the hierarchy important? I can see that PortalSellingCategory can also be inside another PortalSellingCategory. If not maybe you could try the following select:

```
xml.SelectNodes("//PortalSellingCategory");
```

This will search for every node named "PortalSellingCategory" in your response, no mather where in the hierarchy it is.

**EDIT**:
And yes, you should look out for the namespaces, sry for didnt seeing that.
If you like geeting all the nodes with XPath you must create a new NamespaceManager and at it to your selectNodes call:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.LoadXml(data);

    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("ns", "http://tym2sell.com/PortalService/");

    XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("//ns:PortalSellingCategory", ns);
```

Comment: I suspect the OP will need to specify namespaces as well though... and all of this is more easily done in LINQ to XML, with no need for XPath.

Comment: "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: edited my answer. And yes, Linq would probably be better, but I think at least trying it out this way to check how it works is good...if it sucks afterwards you can still change to Linq. But at the end of the day you still know more than one method to solve this problem.

Comment: How would I go to work if the Hierarchy is important?

Comment: You can use various XPath statements like "//PortalSellingCategory//PortalSellingCategory" to get every PortalSellingCategory which is embedded anywhere in another PortalSellingCategory. But to get every aspect of XPath, maybe look at something like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) for a full overview

Answer (score 0):

I would use XElement instead of XMLDocument, and then use Linq to query or pick the elmements like: XElement xContact = ....

int contactno = (int?)xContact.Element("command").Element("contactperson").Attribute("contactpersonid") ?? -1;

if (xContact.Element("command").Element("contactperson").Element("name").Element("firstname") != null)
  console.writeline(xContact.Element("command").Element("contactperson").Element("name").Element("firstname").Value);

Answer (score 0):

```
    var doc= new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("FilePath"); 
    var nodeList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("PortalSellingCategory");
```

Hi,

It returns the collection of nodes, and you just have to query it to get needed informations.
Feel free to ask help if needed.

Dimitri.